'No Sensor Detected On This Device' Kotlin Android Studio
I'm trying to get my android app to request activity recognition permission when it is not allowed, but I get the message 'No sensor detected on this device when I run the below code. I'm testing on a Samsung s23 ultra
In the manifest file...
"
In the main activity file..
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val requestPermissionLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
        ) { isGranted: Boolean ->
            if (isGranted) {
                // Permission is granted. Continue the action or workflow in your
                // app.
            } else {
                // Explain to the user that the feature is unavailable because the
                // feature requires a permission that the user has denied. At the
                // same time, respect the user's decision. Don't link to system
                // settings in an effort to convince the user to change their
                // decision.
            }
        }

//     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}

If I just set the permissions in the app manually and run the code below, the step counter works
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    loadData()
    resetSteps()

    // Adding a context of SENSOR_SERVICE as Sensor Manager
    sensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
}

Looking for a way to have a popup to request step tracking permissions
